# Adding Word "CHAPTER" above each chapter name in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I would like a toc in which the word "CHAPTER" and its number appears just above the name of the chapter just like this

[image]

and here is my output

[image]

Any idea how I could get that?

Here is my Latex code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}

\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill  Page\par}
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[block]{\bfseries\large\filleft}{}{0em}{\MakeUppercase}[{\titlerule[1pt]}]
\titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]{\bfseries\huge\filleft}{\chaptername~\thechapter}{3ex}{\MakeUppercase}[{\titlerule[1pt]}]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{FIRST CHAPTER}
\chapter{SECOND CHAPTER}
\chapter{THIRD CHAPTER}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `\cftchappresnum` and `\cftchapaftersnumb`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{CHAPTER }
\renewcommand{\cftchapnumwidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\\}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}

\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill  Page\par}
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[block]{\bfseries\large\filleft}{}{0em}{\MakeUppercase}[{\titlerule[1pt]}]
\titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]{\bfseries\huge\filleft}{\chaptername~\thechapter}{3ex}{\MakeUppercase}[{\titlerule[1pt]}]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{FIRST CHAPTER}
\chapter{SECOND CHAPTER}
\chapter{THIRD CHAPTER}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**: Regarding your additional questions

For additional space use `\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{\\[5pt]}`. Change the `5pt` to your liking.

For the appendix use `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\cftchappresnum{APPENDIX }}` right before the first chapter in your appendix. Alternatively, if you use `\appendix` to start your appendix you could as well use the following in your preamble:

```
\edef\appendix%
  {%
    \unexpanded\expandafter
      {%
        \appendix
        \addtocontents{toc}
          {\protect\renewcommand\protect\cftchappresnum{APPENDIX }}%
      }%
  }
```

Comment: thank you very much, it works. There are 2 more thing I would like ask. The first is that I would like to add some vertical space between the word "CHAPTER " and its name. The second is that I would like to use "APPENDIX" above each appendix chapter. The code below write "CHAPTER A". How can i get to write "APPENDIX A" instead of "CHAPTER A"